# WM_PAINT message, BeginPaint loop

Tags: winapi, gdi, wm-paint

I can't understand why I got a loop on BeginPaint function. I have already read posts about this kind of loop but almost all of them recommend: "Don't forget to use BeginPaint function on WM_PAINT message, because it entails subsequent WM_PAINT messages otherwise". This isn't my case. May you give me some advices?

**This is my windowclass ("CWindow"):**

```
class CWindow {
public:

   CWindow();
   virtual ~CWindow();
   bool RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
   bool CreateWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance);
   bool Show(int nShow);
private:

    HWND handleWindow;
    ATOM atom;
    bool isRegistered;
    bool isCreated;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void OnPaint();
    void OnDestroy();
};
```

**WndProc function.**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CWindow::WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{  
    CWindow* windowPtr = reinterpret_cast<CWindow*> ( GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA ) );
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch( msg ) {  
        case WM_PAINT:
            // There is a loop right here!
            hdc = BeginPaint( windowPtr->handleWindow,  &ps );
            // The code below doesn't executed!
            RECT rect;
            (void)GetClientRect(windowPtr->handleWindow, &rect);

            (void)DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows 98!"), -1, &rect,
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

            EndPaint( windowPtr->handleWindow, &ps );
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            windowPtr->OnDestroy();
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**RegisterClass**

```
bool CWindow::RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    const TCHAR app_name[] = TEXT("HelloWin");
    WNDCLASSEX  windowClass;

    ZeroMemory( &windowClass, sizeof(windowClass) );
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(windowClass);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon = 0;
    windowClass.hIcon = 0;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = 0;
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = app_name;
    windowClass.hIconSm = NULL;

    atom = RegisterClassEx( &windowClass );
    DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
    if( errorCode ) {
        isRegistered = 0;
        std::wcout << L"ErrorCode: " << errorCode << std::endl;
    } else {
        isRegistered = 1;
    }
    return isRegistered;
}
```

**CreateWindow**

```
bool CWindow::CreateWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    handleWindow = CreateWindow((PCTSTR)atom,               // window class name or atom
                         TEXT("The Hello Program"),  // window caption
                         WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x size
                         CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y size
                         NULL,                       // parent window handle
                         NULL,                       // window menu handle
                         hInstance,                  // program instance handle
                         NULL);                      // creation parameters 
    DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
    if( !handleWindow ) {
        isCreated = 0;
    } else { 
        isCreated = 1;
    }
    return isCreated;
}
```

**Show**

```
bool CWindow::Show(int nShow)
{
    if( isCreated ) {
        ShowWindow( handleWindow, nShow );
        return UpdateWindow( handleWindow );
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**WinMain**

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevINstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShow )
{
    CWindow window;
    window.RegisterClass( hInstance );
    window.CreateWnd( hInstance );
    window.Show( nShow );
    int response = 0;
    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) ) {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [1.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s2lNotdlYcXauzvF2KgwmaQHvxxl5WS8/view?usp=sharing) - I started debugging mode. Pressed **"continue"** button and got a loop on the first breakpoint. Each press returns me to the same line. 


[2.png] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rrEkbv0V8wlYeQmSTThNNd7KeX3ZTy7X/view?usp=sharing) - The window appeared but there is no "Hello message" in the center.

Comment: As you can see in your debugger, `windowPtr` has a value of 0x00000000. You are running a 32-bit build presumably on a 64-bit version of Windows (i.e. running in the WoW64 emulator). As this is Windows 7, the access violation exception is silently suppressed, as explained in my answer. To verify this, simply build and launch a 64-bit application. Under this scenario, your application should crash. Generic advice here is: If you don't understand the anatomy of a Win32 GUI application, don't attempt to write an abstraction layer. You'll fail, as evidenced by this question.

Comment: You forgot to write the message handler for WM_NCCREATE.  That's the correct time to call SetWindowLongPtr, using the passed in CREATESTRUCT.lpCreateParams.  Change the CreateWindow() call as well, last argument should be *this*.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's assuming, that `WM_NCCREATE` is indeed the first message ever sent to a window procedure. That assumption is wrong; a window procedure can receive `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` prior to any other messages. The correct time to attach the window handle to the window instance depends on the documented contract of your library. If you promise to pass all messages through your C++ abstraction, you'll have to set up a hook. See the MFC source for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you never call `SetWindowLongPtr`,

```
CWindow* windowPtr = reinterpret_cast<CWindow*>( GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA ) );
```

returns a `nullptr`, that you subsequently try to dereference:

```
BeginPaint( windowPtr->handleWindow,  &ps )
```

That will trigger an access violation exception, causing the `BeginPaint` call to never even get executed, leaving the invalid region as is. As a consequence, the system keeps generating `WM_PAINT` messages. That's the same issue as not calling `BeginPaint` altogether.<sup>1</sup>

To solve this, you'll either have to attach the window handle to the window instance by calling `SetWindowLongPtr`, or simply use the `hWnd` parameter that's passed into your `CWindow::WindowProc`.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Note that the system silently handles unhandled exceptions in your [WindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573.aspx) on 64-bit versions of Windows under certain conditions.*

Comment: The second way was the solution. I have changed **windowPtr->handleWindow** to **hWnd**. [solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rjcC54EOzWMNE5OTkrm6GDDDG9G5KgJq)

Comment: @DaniilVorobeyv: Both are valid solutions. Although you should probably arrange for space in the windows' private memory area to store your window private data (by setting `cbWndExtra` to `sizeof(HWND)`, and calling `Set|GetWindowLongPtr` with an index of 0).